# Why does cflocation strip characters and not visit the URL?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have a URL stored as:

```
<cfset VisitURL = 'http://www.toysexample.com/search.aspx?searchBox=christmasgifts≠Sort=high&search=new' />
```

(The above URL string actually comes from a database field that I have no control over)

When I ask `cflocation` to visit the above URL like this:

```
<cflocation url="#EncodeForURL(VisitURL)#" addtoken="no" />
```

It visits the URL as a subfolder within my site. So I end up going to the URL `http://www.volumeoneexample.com/http:/www.toysexample.com/search.aspx?searchBox=christmasgifts≠Sort=high&search=new`

As you can see it has dropped one of the forward-slashes from the `http://` part and also appended the URL as a folder within my site. I don't get why its doing this?

Comment: why are you using EncodeForUrl()?. Also, whats with the special character between christmasgifts and Sort in the url query string.. christmasgifts≠Sort. Can you try removing the EncodeURL and that special character and try again.?

Comment: @Sanjeev That special character HAS to exist. Its not a URL on my site but a third-party. Without it the URL is inaccessible. The only way I can keep the special character in the URL is to use `EncodeForURL` or else it gets stripped out.

Comment: don't encode the whole url, encode only the *param **values***.

Comment: Please use URLEncodedFormat() than EncodeForURL()

Comment: @KevinB I can't. The entire URL is stored in a database colum field. I can't split out the URL string.

Comment: Then encode it before it goes in. Either way, it must be properly encoded separately. You cannot encode the whole thing.

Comment: Why the downvote? @KevinB Why can't I encode the whole thing? Just wondering.

Comment: Because by doing so you cause the url to be invalid.

Comment: You can use list functions to separate the url from the query string.

Comment: you would have to split each url on the first `?`, then split the remaining on the first `=` after the beginning or following a `&`, and then encode each of the values. then you would have to piece it all back together.

Comment: @Sanjeev `URLEncodedFormat()` is so CF 9. `EncodeForURL()` is the new hotness. Get with the now. `HTMLEditFormat()` and `JSStringFormat()` are also deprecated in favor of the newer `EncodeFor*` contextual encoding functions.

Comment: @KevinB if I just do this `<cflocation url="#VisitURL#" addtoken="no" />` then why does ColdFusion visit the URL correctly but strips out the `≠` character? Why can't it just visit the string given to it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you copy and paste that url into the address bar in your browser?

Comment: @volumeone because the string isn't a valid url. we've already been over this!

Comment: @DanBracuk it works fine if I do that. its just the EXACT same string for some reason gets stripped of characters when in the `cflocation` tag. It shouldn't do that I feel.

Comment: @KevinB how can it not be a valid URL when it works fine when i visit it through the browser?

Comment: It's valid until you encode it... omg it feels like i'm talking to a wall. what's *invalid* is the param value.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not encoding it! I just said if I do this `<cflocation url="#VisitURL#" addtoken="no" />` where NO encoding takes places, the cflocation tag still strips out the `≠` character but the exact same URL string that is within `#VisitURL#` can be visited fine using any browser

Comment: Right, because the ≠ character needs to be encoded. Chrome is fixing it for you.

Comment: @KevinB okay I didn't realise that. trying to break apart the URL and reassemble it didn't work so well, but this did: `<cflocation url="#DecodeFromURL(EncodeForURL(VisitURL))#" addtoken="no" />` for now. May not be the best / correct way i guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're "over encoding". The EncodeForURL() should only be on the URL parameters.

Since you're not able to retrieve the URL and parameters separately, you *might* be able to get away with treating them like a list.

```
<cflocation url="#ListFirst(VisitURL,"?")#?#EncodeForURL(ListRest(VisitURL,"?"))#" />
```

If things get a little wonky you'll need to do more manipulation than that.

Comment: if I just do this `<cflocation url="#VisitURL#" addtoken="no" />` then why does ColdFusion visit the URL but strips out the `≠` character? Why can't it just visit the string given to it?

Comment: Probably because that's not a valid character for an URL, and so needs to be encoded.

Comment: I just tried `<cflocation url="#DecodeFromURL(EncodeForURL(VisitURL))#" addtoken="no" />` and it seems to work nicely, but I would rather not have to do any of this and force `cflocation` to go the string specified rather than do its own thing and strip out characters!